# Multi stage & gain opamp output voltage issue

Tags: operational-amplifier, photodiode, transimpedance

[image]

I am currently facing an issue with an opamp circuit.

The design consists of a transimpedance amplifier followed by a buffer stage and then followed by 6 non inverting gain stages (each stage 4 times the last stage.)

I am using the OPA192, OPA2192 & OPA4192 precision opamps from TI.

What I have found is that when the photodiode is covered (darkened) I can see close to 4mV on x1 - x16 gain stages.  On anything after this gain stage, I can see the voltage reduce and go negative. This is an issue because the opamps are connected to an ADC that only reads 0-5V DC signals.

Please note that the opamps are running on dual supplies (+/-5V).
Does anyone know what could be the issue?

Please also note that I only see this on some opamp circuits but not others.

Comment: Your schematic doesn't match your explanation so is hard to follow. the schematic shows a single TIA followed by a G=1k stage

Comment: The DC gain in your circuit is **HUGE**. the 2nd stage has a DC gain of ~1000 ! That means 1 mV offset at the input will be amplified to 1 V at the output. Also you didn't design for the lowest offset as the + input has 0 Ohm to the output of the first opamp while the - input sees 174 ohm. You should learn how to design for low offset, watch this EEVBlog: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TxBJb-Z0XFI  also, if possible, reduce the gain at DC. Realize that two stages in series with each a gain of 32 often five better results than one stage with a gain of 1000.

Comment: Your comments say that the first stage is a buffer, but it in fact has a gain of **1024!** Your design doesn't match the description in the post.

Answer (score 1):

Your diode is positioned as a photodiode. It will generate a voltage when you expose it to light.
[image: Photodiode showing current flow on illumination]

The voltage increases on exposure to light and you are connecting that voltage to an op amp wired as an INVERTING amplifier. Since the downstream op Amps do not invert again, your output will track with the first inverting amplifier.  An inverting amplifier's output will go more negative as the input goes more positive.

As for your voltage in darkness.  If you expect zero, you have two issues to look at.
First: every op amp has some "input offset voltage". That is, when the + and - inputs are connected to the same voltage, the output is not perfectly zero.  So one input has to be adjusted slightly to get a 0V output.  If you have only 4mV output after several stages of amplification, you are pretty lucky.

Second, your LED is connected to the "-" input on the op amp and that input has the feedback resistor connected to it.  That 330k resistor can supply 5 to 15 microAmps to the photodiode and give it a positive voltage. A sensitive photodiode should be on the "+" input to avoid the interference from the feedback resistor.

Finally, all electro optical devices, including photodiodes, have some "dark current" (also known as reverse bias leakage current).  See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_current_(physics)

Good luck